Variable/Struct value getting nil when passed to ParDo function
Hi I'm trying to write a beam pipeline where we first read the data from bigquery then do transformation on each row (if the value is present in map, use it else insert the value in map and use it) and then writes it to bigquery. I've written the following code
// Row struct for bigquery
type Row struct {
    Operation      string    `bigquery:"operation"`
    SrcZone        string    `bigquery:"src_zone"`
    BucketLocation string    `bigquery:"bucket_location"`
    BucketName     string    `bigquery:"bucket_name"`

}

// UserDataMap struct for user data
type UserDataMap struct {
    mu   sync.Mutex
    data map[string]string
}

func init() {
    beam.RegisterFunction(transformRow)
    // beam.RegisterFunction(writeData)
    beam.RegisterType(reflect.TypeOf((*Row)(nil)).Elem())
    beam.RegisterType(reflect.TypeOf((*UserDataMap)(nil)).Elem())
}

func (dataMap *UserDataMap) ProcessElement(ctx context.Context, row Row, emit func(beam.X)) error {
    dataMap.mu.Lock()
    defer dataMap.mu.Unlock()

    fmt.Printf("map: %v\n", dataMap.data)

    if _, ok := dataMap.data[row.SrcZone]; !ok {
        dataMap.data[row.SrcZone] = uuid.New()
    }
    row.SrcZone = dataMap.data[row.SrcZone]
    emit(row)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    project := "pulkitaggarwal-gcs-prober"
    ipDataset := "benchmarks"
    ipTable := "latency_results"
    opDataset := "dataflow_dataset"
    opTable := "dataflow_table"

    ctx := context.Background()
    beam.Init()

    p := beam.NewPipeline()
    s := p.Root()

    rows := bigqueryio.Read(s, project, fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s.%s", project, ipDataset, ipTable), reflect.TypeOf(Row{}))

    dataMap := &UserDataMap{data: make(map[string]string)}
    transformedRows := beam.ParDo(s, dataMap, rows, beam.TypeDefinition{Var: beam.XType, T: reflect.TypeOf(Row{})})

    bigqueryio.Write(s, project, fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s.%s", project, opDataset, opTable), transformedRows)

    if err := beamx.Run(ctx, p); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("failed to run pipeline: %v", err)
    }
}

But it throws the error panic: assignment to entry in nil map. Looks like UserDataMap is getting passed as nil.
I've even tried passing everything by reference but still getting the same error. Any argument that I try to pass in ParDo function is getting nil. I don't know why it is happening or is there something I'm missing?

This question is similar to: Runtime error: assignment to entry in nil map. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Without really understanding the pipeline and how it is set-up, it is clear that without any constructor defined which actually initializes the map, you're basically trying to write to a nil map which causes the panic you're seeing.
A hack around this would be to check whether the map is nil after acquiring the lock:
dataMap.mu.Lock()
defer dataMap.mu.Unlock()
if dataMap.data == nil { 
   dataMap.data = make(map[string]string) 
}


The proper solution, however, would be to have a constructor function that would create an initialized instance of UserDataMap, like:
func NewUserDataMap() *UserDataMap {
 return &UserDataMap{ data: make(map[string]string }
}

After calling the constructor, you'd somehow pass the correct, initialized instance to the pipeline.
Another option would be to use pluggable functions and just scope the maps that you need through anonymous functions in main.
